# Spring MVC form input type date value is always null

Tags: html, spring, date, spring-mvc

jsp

```
<form:input path="gantry.dateOfComm" type="date" class="form-control" id="txtDate"/>
```

domain class

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="DATE_OF_COMM")
    private Date dateOfComm;

public Date getDateOfComm() {
        return this.dateOfComm;
    }

    public void setDateOfComm(Date dateOfComm) {
        this.dateOfComm = dateOfComm;
    }
```

when I print the value of date it return null
how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You require html attribute "name" in jsp page to make it identifiable with controller. Can you modify your code as below and retry

```
<form:input path="gantry.dateOfComm" name="dateOfComm" type="date" class="form-control" id="txtDate"/>
```

Comment: sill return null

Answer (score 0):

Data mapping between JSP and Controller is done based on `name` attribute.

I don't see any `"name"` value for your input

Please add `name="dateOfComm"` like this and try

```
<form:input path="gantry.dateOfComm" type="date" class="form-control" id="txtDate" name="dateOfComm" />
```

Comment: If you are refering name as dateOfComm from some object you need to refer same here maybe name="gantry.dateOfComm" 
Also add full JSP form if still it doesnt work.